# TypeError: argument of type is not iterable Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Tengo un problema a la hora de ejecutar un programa de python con PyQt5,tengo una funcion que ejecuta un login, pero a la hora de clickar el boton salta el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'Login' is not iterable
```

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
class Login(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Login,self).__init__()
        loadUi("/home/lvapython/Escritorio/Tutoriales-Pytho/qt     /login.ui",self)
        self.login_button.clicked.connect(self.comprobar_login)

    def log(self):
        email = self.correo_entry.text()
        password = self.pass_entry.text()
        return email, password


    def comprobar_login(email,password):
        if "@" in email:
            print("Correo correcto")
        else:
            print("Correo incorrecto")

        if len(password) >= 4 and len(password) <= 15:
            print('Contraseña Correcta')
        else:
            print("La contraseña tiene que tener entre 4 y 15 digitos")
```

Answer (score 0):

Es extraño que se espere que un slot obtendra magicamente datos. En este caso se debe invocar a la funcion `log`:

```py
def comprobar_login(self):
    email,password = self.log()

    if "@" in email:
        print("Correo correcto")
    else:
        print("Correo incorrecto")

    if len(password) >= 4 and len(password) <= 15:
        print('Contraseña Correcta')
    else:
        print("La contraseña tiene que tener entre 4 y 15 digitos")
```